# failing to resize this table

Tags: tables

Can anyone help make this table fit on a page?

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{llllcl}
\tiny System:INFLATION AND  UNEMPLOYMENT        Estimation\\ \tiny Method: Least Squares\\      \tiny Sample: 1989 2014\\               
\tiny Included observations: 26 \\          
\tiny Total system (balanced) observations 52\\ \hline\hline             &\tiny Coefficient &\tiny Std. Error   &\tiny t-Statistic  &\tiny Prob.\\ \hline\hline  

\tiny C(1)  &\tiny 0.262395  &\tiny 0.364940    &\tiny 0.719009 &\tiny 0.4814\\
\tiny C(2)  &\tiny -0.595551    &\tiny 0.622512 &\tiny -0.956690    &\tiny 0.3514\\
\tiny C(3)  &\tiny 0.279303 &\tiny 0.515167 &\tiny 0.542160 &\tiny 0.5944\\
\tiny C(4)  &\tiny 0.093994 &\tiny 0.621750 &\tiny 0.151177 &\tiny 0.8815\\
\tiny C(5)  &\tiny -0.442089    &\tiny 0.436318 &\tiny -1.013228    &\tiny 0.3244\\
\tiny C(6)  &\tiny 1.575771 &\tiny 2.109222 &\tiny 0.747086 &\tiny 0.4647\\
\tiny C(7)  &\tiny -4.662746    &\tiny 5.343604 &\tiny -0.872585    &\tiny 0.3944\\
\tiny C(8)  &\tiny 2.824077 &\tiny 3.638512 &\tiny 0.776163 &\tiny 0.4477\\
\tiny C(9)  &\tiny 0.176143 &\tiny 0.105336 &\tiny 1.672193 &\tiny 0.1118\\
\tiny C(10) &\tiny 0.157414 &\tiny 0.115267 &\tiny 1.365650 &\tiny 0.1889\\
\tiny C(11) \tiny &\tiny 0.325583   \tiny &\tiny 0.133983   &\tiny 2.430036 \tiny &\tiny 0.0258\\
\tiny C(12)  &\tiny -0.044040   &\tiny0.175836   &\tiny -0.250462   &\tiny 0.8051\\
\tiny C(13)  &\tiny 0.290630    &\tiny 0.232195 &\tiny 1.251663 &\tiny 0.2267\\
\tiny C(14) &\tiny 0.008564 &\tiny 0.193656 &\tiny 0.044225 &\tiny 0.9652\\
\tiny C(15) &\tiny 0.387795 &\tiny 0.165762 &\tiny2.339464  &\tiny 0.0310\\
\tiny C(16) &\tiny 0.243521 &\tiny 0.306769 &\tiny 0.793826 &\tiny 0.4376\\
\tiny C(17) &\tiny 4.818044 &\tiny 6.983893 &\tiny 0.689879 &\tiny 0.4991\\
\tiny C(18) &\tiny 1.064356 &\tiny 1.132110 &\tiny 0.940152 &\tiny 0.3596\\
\tiny C(19) &\tiny -1.150959    &\tiny 1.931147 &\tiny -0.595998    &\tiny 0.5586\\
\tiny C(20) &\tiny 0.654313 &\tiny 1.598142 &\tiny 0.409421 &\tiny 0.6871\\
\tiny C(21) &\tiny -0.595249    &\tiny 1.928781 &\tiny -0.308614    &\tiny 0.7612\\
\tiny C(22) &\tiny -1.357195    &\tiny 1.353537 &\tiny -1.002702    &\tiny 0.3293\\
\tiny C(23) &\tiny 4.566426 &\tiny 6.543192 &\tiny 0.697890 &\tiny 0.4942\\
\tiny C(24) &\tiny -20.04091    &\tiny 16.57683 &\tiny -1.208971    &\tiny 0.2423\\
\tiny C(25) &\tiny 14.40853 &\tiny 11.28733 &\tiny 1.276523 &\tiny 0.2180\\
\tiny C(26) &\tiny -0.175476    &\tiny 0.326772 &\tiny -0.536997    &\tiny 0.5978\\
\tiny C(27) &\tiny 0.381407 &\tiny 0.357579 &\tiny 1.066639 &\tiny 0.3002\\
\tiny C(28) &\tiny 0.158697 &\tiny 0.415639 &\tiny 0.381815 &\tiny 0.7071\\
\tiny C(29) &\tiny -1.169850    &\tiny 0.545476 &\tiny -2.144640    &\tiny 0.0459\\
\tiny C(30) &\tiny 0.600688 &\tiny 0.720311 &\tiny 0.833929 &\tiny 0.4153\\
\tiny C(31) &\tiny 0.764571 &\tiny 0.600755 &\tiny 1.272683 &\tiny 0.2193\\
\tiny C(32) &\tiny 1.138401 &\tiny 0.514224 &\tiny 2.213823 &\tiny 0.0400\\
\tiny C(33) &\tiny -0.139137 &\tiny 0.951653    &\tiny -0.146206    &\tiny 0.8854\\
\tiny C(34) &\tiny 10.13866 &\tiny 21.66531 &\tiny 0.467967 &\tiny 0.6454\\ \hline\hline
\tiny Determinant residual covariance       &\tiny 19.24770\\   \hline\hline    
\tiny \bf UNT
\tiny Observations: 26\\                
\tiny R-squared &\tiny 0.880742     &\tiny Mean dependent var       &\tiny 4.645045\\
\tiny Adjusted R-squared    &\tiny 0.668727     &\tiny S.D. dependent var       &\tiny 3.567955\\
\tiny S.E. of regression    &\tiny 2.053583     &\tiny Sum squared resid        &\tiny 37.95483\\
\tiny Durbin-Watson stat    &\tiny 1.507160\\ \hline\hline      
\tiny\bf INF
\tiny Observations: 26\\                
\tiny R-squared &\tiny 0.839385     &\tiny Mean dependent var       &\tiny 1.873077\\
\tiny Adjusted R-squared    &\tiny 0.553847     &\tiny S.D. dependent var       &\tiny 9.537570\\
\tiny S.E. of regression    &\tiny 6.370588     &\tiny Sum squared resid        &\tiny 365.2596\\
\tiny Durbin-Watson stat    &\tiny 2.092647\\ \hline    
\end{subtable}%     
                \end{tabular}
\end{table}         
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you indent lines of code by four spaces -- achieved most easily by highlighting the lines and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the line above the editing window -- the site software will automatically pretty-print the code.

Comment: `%s/\\tiny//g` and place one `\tiny` after beginning the `table` (not `tabular`)

Answer (score 3):

The 216 [!] `\tiny` instructions aren't needed. Do get rid of the `\end{subtable}` directive. I suggest you break up the single, large `tabular` environment into two separate ones: the first should contain the 5 header lines and the estimates for the 34 regressors, and the second should contain the regression's summary statistics. Splitting the material into two separate `tabular` environments makes it easier to organize the information more compactly.

I would also like to suggest you align the numeric data on their respective decimal markers; this can be done by using the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package. The latter also lets you round the numbers and automatically show fewer digits after decimal markers. (Do you really need to show 6 places after the decimal?) Finally, the material in the five header lines should not be aligned with the remaining material in the first `tabular`.

Aside: I can't help but make a few remarks about the regression results shown in this table. Even though I don't know what the dependent variable or the independent variable are, I do find it potentially worrisome that only 4 of the 34 regressors are individually statistically significant. Are most of the other 30 regressors either worthless or (nearly) multi-collinear? Running a regression with 34 regressors on a sample with just 52 observations raises more than just a couple of red flags. I hope your paper addresses these concerns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page size parameters
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[group-digits=false,
            round-mode=places, % turn on automatic rounding
            round-precision=5]{siunitx} 
\newcommand\ml[1]{\multicolumn{5}{l}{#1}} % shortcut macro, for header lines
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]

\centering

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-2.5] 
                 S[table-format= 2.5] 
                 S[table-format=-1.5] 
                 S[table-format= 1.4,round-mode=off] }

 \ml{System: INFLATION AND  UNEMPLOYMENT} \\
 \ml{Estimation Method: Least Squares} \\
 \ml{Sample: 1989--2014}\\
 \ml{Included observations: 26}\\
 \ml{Total system (balanced) observations: 52}\\
 \addlinespace
 \toprule 
  & {\ \ Coeff.} & {Std.\ Err.} & {t-Stat.} & {Prob.}\\ 
 \midrule 
 C(1)  & 0.262395  & 0.364940    & 0.719009 & 0.4814\\
 C(2)  & -0.595551    & 0.622512 & -0.956690    & 0.3514\\
 C(3)  & 0.279303 & 0.515167 & 0.542160 & 0.5944\\
 C(4)  & 0.093994 & 0.621750 & 0.151177 & 0.8815\\
 C(5)  & -0.442089    & 0.436318 & -1.013228    & 0.3244\\
 C(6)  & 1.575771 & 2.109222 & 0.747086 & 0.4647\\
 C(7)  & -4.662746    & 5.343604 & -0.872585    & 0.3944\\
 C(8)  & 2.824077 & 3.638512 & 0.776163 & 0.4477\\
 C(9)  & 0.176143 & 0.105336 & 1.672193 & 0.1118\\
 C(10) & 0.157414 & 0.115267 & 1.365650 & 0.1889\\
 C(11)  & 0.325583    & 0.133983   & 2.430036  & 0.0258\\
 C(12)  & -0.044040   &0.175836   & -0.250462   & 0.8051\\
 C(13)  & 0.290630    & 0.232195 & 1.251663 & 0.2267\\
 C(14) & 0.008564 & 0.193656 & 0.044225 & 0.9652\\
 C(15) & 0.387795 & 0.165762 &2.339464  & 0.0310\\
 C(16) & 0.243521 & 0.306769 & 0.793826 & 0.4376\\
 C(17) & 4.818044 & 6.983893 & 0.689879 & 0.4991\\
 C(18) & 1.064356 & 1.132110 & 0.940152 & 0.3596\\
 C(19) & -1.150959    & 1.931147 & -0.595998    & 0.5586\\
 C(20) & 0.654313 & 1.598142 & 0.409421 & 0.6871\\
 C(21) & -0.595249    & 1.928781 & -0.308614    & 0.7612\\
 C(22) & -1.357195    & 1.353537 & -1.002702    & 0.3293\\
 C(23) & 4.566426 & 6.543192 & 0.697890 & 0.4942\\
 C(24) & -20.04091    & 16.57683 & -1.208971    & 0.2423\\
 C(25) & 14.40853 & 11.28733 & 1.276523 & 0.2180\\
 C(26) & -0.175476    & 0.326772 & -0.536997    & 0.5978\\
 C(27) & 0.381407 & 0.357579 & 1.066639 & 0.3002\\
 C(28) & 0.158697 & 0.415639 & 0.381815 & 0.7071\\
 C(29) & -1.169850    & 0.545476 & -2.144640    & 0.0459\\
 C(30) & 0.600688 & 0.720311 & 0.833929 & 0.4153\\
 C(31) & 0.764571 & 0.600755 & 1.272683 & 0.2193\\
 C(32) & 1.138401 & 0.514224 & 2.213823 & 0.0400\\
 C(33) & -0.139137 & 0.951653    & -0.146206    & 0.8854\\
 C(34) & 10.13866 & 21.66531 & 0.467967 & 0.6454\\ 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1.5] 
                lS[table-format=3.3,round-precision=3]}
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{Determinant residual covariance: 19.24770}\\ 
 \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries UNT Observations: 26}\\                
 R-squared & 0.880742     & Mean dependent var       & 4.645045\\
 Adjusted R-squared    & 0.668727     & S.D. dependent var       & 3.567955\\
 S.E. of regression    & 2.053583     & Sum squared resid        & 37.95483\\
 Durbin-Watson stat    & 1.507160\\ 
\addlinespace
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries INF Observations: 26}\\                
 R-squared & 0.839385     & Mean dependent var       & 1.873077\\
 Adjusted R-squared    & 0.553847     & S.D. dependent var       & 9.537570\\
 S.E. of regression    & 6.370588     & Sum squared resid        & 365.2596\\
 Durbin-Watson stat    & 2.092647\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}         
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty at all.

[image: makondoTable]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{table}
        \tiny
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
             System:INFLATION AND  UNEMPLOYMENT        Estimation\par  Method: Least Squares\par       Sample: 1989 2014\par               
             Included observations: 26 \medbreak
        \begin{tabular}{llllcl}
             Total system (balanced) observations 52\\ \toprule             & Coefficient & Std. Error   & t-Statistic  & Prob.\\ \midrule

             C(1)  & 0.262395  & 0.364940    & 0.719009 & 0.4814\\
             C(2)  & -0.595551    & 0.622512 & -0.956690    & 0.3514\\
             C(3)  & 0.279303 & 0.515167 & 0.542160 & 0.5944\\
             C(4)  & 0.093994 & 0.621750 & 0.151177 & 0.8815\\
             C(5)  & -0.442089    & 0.436318 & -1.013228    & 0.3244\\
             C(6)  & 1.575771 & 2.109222 & 0.747086 & 0.4647\\
             C(7)  & -4.662746    & 5.343604 & -0.872585    & 0.3944\\
             C(8)  & 2.824077 & 3.638512 & 0.776163 & 0.4477\\
             C(9)  & 0.176143 & 0.105336 & 1.672193 & 0.1118\\
             C(10) & 0.157414 & 0.115267 & 1.365650 & 0.1889\\
             C(11)  & 0.325583    & 0.133983   & 2.430036  & 0.0258\\
             C(12)  & -0.044040   &0.175836   & -0.250462   & 0.8051\\
             C(13)  & 0.290630    & 0.232195 & 1.251663 & 0.2267\\
             C(14) & 0.008564 & 0.193656 & 0.044225 & 0.9652\\
             C(15) & 0.387795 & 0.165762 &2.339464  & 0.0310\\
             C(16) & 0.243521 & 0.306769 & 0.793826 & 0.4376\\
             C(17) & 4.818044 & 6.983893 & 0.689879 & 0.4991\\
             C(18) & 1.064356 & 1.132110 & 0.940152 & 0.3596\\
             C(19) & -1.150959    & 1.931147 & -0.595998    & 0.5586\\
             C(20) & 0.654313 & 1.598142 & 0.409421 & 0.6871\\
             C(21) & -0.595249    & 1.928781 & -0.308614    & 0.7612\\
             C(22) & -1.357195    & 1.353537 & -1.002702    & 0.3293\\
             C(23) & 4.566426 & 6.543192 & 0.697890 & 0.4942\\
             C(24) & -20.04091    & 16.57683 & -1.208971    & 0.2423\\
             C(25) & 14.40853 & 11.28733 & 1.276523 & 0.2180\\
             C(26) & -0.175476    & 0.326772 & -0.536997    & 0.5978\\
             C(27) & 0.381407 & 0.357579 & 1.066639 & 0.3002\\
             C(28) & 0.158697 & 0.415639 & 0.381815 & 0.7071\\
             C(29) & -1.169850    & 0.545476 & -2.144640    & 0.0459\\
             C(30) & 0.600688 & 0.720311 & 0.833929 & 0.4153\\
             C(31) & 0.764571 & 0.600755 & 1.272683 & 0.2193\\
             C(32) & 1.138401 & 0.514224 & 2.213823 & 0.0400\\
             C(33) & -0.139137 & 0.951653    & -0.146206    & 0.8854\\
             C(34) & 10.13866 & 21.66531 & 0.467967 & 0.6454\\ \midrule
             Determinant residual covariance       & 19.24770\\   \midrule
             \bfseries UNT
             Observations: 26\\                
             R-squared & 0.880742     & Mean dependent var       & 4.645045\\
             Adjusted R-squared    & 0.668727     & S.D. dependent var       & 3.567955\\
             S.E. of regression    & 2.053583     & Sum squared resid        & 37.95483\\
             Durbin-Watson stat    & 1.507160\\ \midrule
            \bfseries INF
             Observations: 26\\                
             R-squared & 0.839385     & Mean dependent var       & 1.873077\\
             Adjusted R-squared    & 0.553847     & S.D. dependent var       & 9.537570\\
             S.E. of regression    & 6.370588     & Sum squared resid        & 365.2596\\
             Durbin-Watson stat    & 2.092647\\ \bottomrule    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}         
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess, that OP actually like have two different tables.

Answer (score 2):

It can fit on one page with `\footnotesize` and look a little nicer, , removing `\arraystretch` and playing with `\rlap` and `\makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \centering\sisetup{table-number-alignment = center}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
  \footnotesize\centering
 % \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} \medbreak
        \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-2.6]S[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=3.6]S[table-format=1.4]}
             \rlap{\makecell[l]{System: INFLATION AND UNEMPLOYMENT Estimation\\
             Method: Least Squares\\
              Sample: 1989 2014\\
           included observations: 26}}\\
\addlinespace
\rlap{\bfseries Total system (balanced) observations 52}\\
             \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
             & {Coefficient} & {Std. Error} & {t-Statistic} & {Prob.}\\
              \midrule
             C(1) & 0.262395 & 0.364940 & 0.719009 & 0.4814\\
             C(2) & -0.595551 & 0.622512 & -0.956690 & 0.3514\\
             C(3) & 0.279303 & 0.515167 & 0.542160 & 0.5944\\
             C(4) & 0.093994 & 0.621750 & 0.151177 & 0.8815\\
             C(5) & -0.442089 & 0.436318 & -1.013228 & 0.3244\\
             C(6) & 1.575771 & 2.109222 & 0.747086 & 0.4647\\
             C(7) & -4.662746 & 5.343604 & -0.872585 & 0.3944\\
             C(8) & 2.824077 & 3.638512 & 0.776163 & 0.4477\\
             C(9) & 0.176143 & 0.105336 & 1.672193 & 0.1118\\
             C(10) & 0.157414 & 0.115267 & 1.365650 & 0.1889\\
             C(11) & 0.325583 & 0.133983 & 2.430036 & 0.0258\\
             C(12) & -0.044040 &0.175836 & -0.250462 & 0.8051\\
             C(13) & 0.290630 & 0.232195 & 1.251663 & 0.2267\\
             C(14) & 0.008564 & 0.193656 & 0.044225 & 0.9652\\
             C(15) & 0.387795 & 0.165762 &2.339464 & 0.0310\\
             C(16) & 0.243521 & 0.306769 & 0.793826 & 0.4376\\
             C(17) & 4.818044 & 6.983893 & 0.689879 & 0.4991\\
             C(18) & 1.064356 & 1.132110 & 0.940152 & 0.3596\\
             C(19) & -1.150959 & 1.931147 & -0.595998 & 0.5586\\
             C(20) & 0.654313 & 1.598142 & 0.409421 & 0.6871\\
             C(21) & -0.595249 & 1.928781 & -0.308614 & 0.7612\\
             C(22) & -1.357195 & 1.353537 & -1.002702 & 0.3293\\
             C(23) & 4.566426 & 6.543192 & 0.697890 & 0.4942\\
             C(24) & -20.04091 & 16.57683 & -1.208971 & 0.2423\\
             C(25) & 14.40853 & 11.28733 & 1.276523 & 0.2180\\
             C(26) & -0.175476 & 0.326772 & -0.536997 & 0.5978\\
             C(27) & 0.381407 & 0.357579 & 1.066639 & 0.3002\\
             C(28) & 0.158697 & 0.415639 & 0.381815 & 0.7071\\
             C(29) & -1.169850 & 0.545476 & -2.144640 & 0.0459\\
             C(30) & 0.600688 & 0.720311 & 0.833929 & 0.4153\\
             C(31) & 0.764571 & 0.600755 & 1.272683 & 0.2193\\
             C(32) & 1.138401 & 0.514224 & 2.213823 & 0.0400\\
             C(33) & -0.139137 & 0.951653 & -0.146206 & 0.8854\\
             C(34) & 10.13866 & 21.66531 & 0.467967 & 0.6454\\
             \midrule
\makecell[l]{ Determinant residual\\ covariance} & 19.24770\\
\midrule
  \rlap{\bfseries UNT Observations: 26}\\
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
 R-squared & 0.880742 & {\eqmakebox[T][l]{Mean dependent var}} & 4.645045\\
 Adjusted R-squared & 0.668727 &{\eqmakebox[T][l]{S.D. dependent var}} & 3.567955\\
 S.E. of regression & 2.053583 & {\eqmakebox[T][l]{Sum squared resid}} & 37.95483\\
 Durbin-Watson stat & 1.507160\\
 \midrule
 \rlap{\bfseries INF Observations: 26}\\
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
 R-squared & 0.839385 & {\eqmakebox[T][l]{Mean dependent var}} & 1.873077\\
 Adjusted R-squared & 0.553847 & {\eqmakebox[T][l]{S.D. dependent var}} & 9.537570\\
 S.E. of regression & 6.370588 & {\eqmakebox[T][l]{Sum squared resid}} & 365.2596\\
 Durbin-Watson stat & 2.092647\\
 \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add to use a subtable environment on two tables like these

Comment: Do you mean having two similar tables, considered as subtables, with one global table caption and two subtable captions?

Comment: yes, but I am new to TEXMAKER

Comment: Well, in this case, you can use the `subfloat` package and have two `subtable` environments nested in a `table` environment.